# Pólya's Theory of Counting

Tags: combinatorics, polya-counting-theory

Consider all vectors $(n_1,n_2,\dots , n_{10})$ with $1\le n_i\le 6$.

> $A)$ Discounting all permutations of the entries, how many vectors are there which use each number $1,2,\dots,6$ at least once.
>
> $B)$ Let $G$ be the group of symmetries generated by $(n_1,n_2,\dots, n_{10})$ to $(n_{10},n_1,n_2,\dots, n_9)$. Discounting the action of $G$, how many vectors are there which use each number $1,2,\dots, 6$ at least once?

I know this is a Pólya's Theory of Counting problem. I don't know to set up the generating function to get the coefficients that I need from the pattern inventory.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions here, one using the Pólya Enumeration
Theorem and another one using Burnside's lemma and Stirling numbers of
the second kind.  The second  solution is much more efficient than the
first one. The answers are $126$ for the action of the symmetric group
and $1643544$ for the cyclic group.

For both solutions we need  the cycle indices of the respective groups
which are

$$Z(S_{10}) = 
1/9\,a_{{9}}a_{{1}}+1/16\,a_{{8}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}+1/42\,a_{{7}}{a_{
{1}}}^{3}+{\frac {a_{{6}}{a_{{1}}}^{4}}{144}}+{\frac {a_{{2}}{a_
{{1}}}^{8}}{80640}}\\+{\frac {a_{{3}}{a_{{1}}}^{7}}{15120}}+{
\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{6}{a_{{2}}}^{2}}{5760}}+{\frac {a_{{4}}{a_{{1}
}}^{6}}{2880}}+{\frac {a_{{5}}{a_{{1}}}^{5}}{600}}+{\frac {{a_{{
1}}}^{4}{a_{{2}}}^{3}}{1152}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{3}}}^{2}
}{432}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{4}}}^{2}}{64}}\\+{\frac {{a_{{1}
}}^{2}{a_{{2}}}^{4}}{768}}+{\frac {a_{{1}}{a_{{3}}}^{3}}{162}}+{
\frac {{a_{{2}}}^{3}a_{{4}}}{192}}+{\frac {{a_{{2}}}^{2}{a_{{3}}
}^{2}}{144}}+1/48\,{a_{{2}}}^{2}a_{{6}}+{\frac {a_{{2}}{a_{{4}}}
^{2}}{64}}\\+1/16\,a_{{2}}a_{{8}}+{\frac {{a_{{3}}}^{2}a_{{4}}}{72
}}+1/21\,a_{{3}}a_{{7}}+1/24\,a_{{4}}a_{{6}}+{\frac {1}{50}}\,{a
_{{5}}}^{2}+1/10\,a_{{10}}\\+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{10}}{3628800}}+{
\frac {{a_{{2}}}^{5}}{3840}}+1/24\,a_{{1}}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}+
{\frac {a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{3}a_{{3}}}{144}}+1/40\,a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}
}^{2}a_{{5}}\\+1/14\,a_{{1}}a_{{2}}a_{{7}}+1/18\,a_{{1}}a_{{3}}a_{
{6}}+1/20\,a_{{1}}a_{{4}}a_{{5}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{2}}}^
{2}a_{{4}}}{64}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{2}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}}{72}}
\\+1/24\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{2}}a_{{6}}+1/30\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{3}}a_{
{5}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{3}{a_{{2}}}^{2}a_{{3}}}{144}}+{\frac {{a
_{{1}}}^{3}a_{{2}}a_{{5}}}{60}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{3}a_{{3}}a_{{
4}}}{72}}\\+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{5}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}}{720}}+{\frac {{a_
{{1}}}^{4}a_{{2}}a_{{4}}}{192}}+1/30\,a_{{2}}a_{{3}}a_{{5}}$$

and
$$Z(C_{10}) =
1/10\,{a_{{1}}}^{10}+1/10\,{a_{{2}}}^{5}+2/5\,{a_{{5}}}^{2}+2/5
\,a_{{10}}.$$

Using a CAS  like Maple we can then  perform coefficient extraction of
all terms in

$$Z(S_{10})(B_1+B_2+\cdots+B_6)$$

and

$$Z(C_{10})(B_1+B_2+\cdots+B_6)$$

that contain all six variables, e.g. from
$$[B_1^5 B_2 \cdots B_6] Z(C_{10})(B_1+B_2+\cdots+B_6).$$

We then sum these and set the six variables to one to get the count we
are interested in. The substitution  follows the standard rule of $a_q
= B_1^q +  B_2^q + \cdots + B_6^q.$ An  excerpt from $Z(C_{10})$ looks
like this:
$$\cdots +504\,B_{{3}}B_{{4}}{B_{{5}}}^{3}{B_{{6}}}^
{5}+252\,B_{{3}}B_{{4}}{B_{{5}}}^{2}{B_{{6}}}^{6}+72\,B_{{3}}B_{{4}
}B_{{5}}{B_{{6}}}^{7}\\+9\,B_{{3}}B_{{4}}{B_{{6}}}^{8}+B_{{3}}{B_{{5}
}}^{9}+9\,B_{{3}}{B_{{5}}}^{8}B_{{6}}+36\,B_{{3}}{B_{{5}}}^{7}{B_{{
6}}}^{2}+84\,B_{{3}}{B_{{5}}}^{6}{B_{{6}}}^{3}\\+126\,B_{{3}}{B_{{5}}
}^{5}{B_{{6}}}^{4}+126\,B_{{3}}{B_{{5}}}^{4}{B_{{6}}}^{5}+84\,B_{{3
}}{B_{{5}}}^{3}{B_{{6}}}^{6}\\+36\,B_{{3}}{B_{{5}}}^{2}{B_{{6}}}^{7}+
9\,B_{{3}}B_{{5}}{B_{{6}}}^{8}+B_{{3}}{B_{{6}}}^{9}\\+{B_{{4}}}^{10}+
{B_{{4}}}^{9}B_{{5}}+{B_{{4}}}^{9}B_{{6}}+5\,{B_{{4}}}^{8}{B_{{5}}}
^{2}+9\,{B_{{4}}}^{8}B_{{5}}B_{{6}}+\cdots$$

This is what the procedures **V1**  and **W1** do. This method is very
costly as  we must carry  out expensive polynomial  exponentiations to
get the coefficients  and coefficients are being computed  that do not
contribute to the desired result.

A  much  more  efficient  approach   is  to  use  the  Burnside  lemma
directly. Given a term from the cycle index $Z(S_{10})$ or $Z(C_{10})$
the admissible assignments  must be constant on each  cycle and in the
context   of  this  particular   problem  all   six  colors   must  be
present. This  means we have  a set partition  of the cycles  into six
non-empty sets where each set  receives one color.  Set partitions are
counted by the Stirling numbers of the second kind. Before we conclude
we need  to take into account  that all $720$ permutations  of the six
colors correspond to  a valid assignment. This gives  a very efficient
algorithm with  good time and  space complexity parameters  (number of
operations  proportional   to  the  number  of  terms   in  the  cycle
index). The algorithm is implemented in **V2** and **W2**.

The Maple code for these was as follows:

```
with(combinat);
with(numtheory);
pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;
res := ind;

polyvars := indets(poly);
indvars := indets(ind);

for v in indvars do
    pot := op(1, v);

    subs1 :=
    [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
         k=1..nops(polyvars))];

    subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

    res := subs(subs2, res);
od;

res;

end;
pet_cycleind_cyclic :=
proc(n)
local d, s;
s := 0;
for d in divisors(n) do
    s := s + phi(d)*a[d]^(n/d);
od;

s/n;

end;
pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
local p, s;
option remember;
if n=0 then return 1; fi;

expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));

end;
pet_flatten_term :=
proc(varp)
local terml, d, cf, v;
terml := [];

cf := varp;
for v in indets(varp) do
    d := degree(varp, v);
    terml := [op(terml), seq(v, k=1..d)];
    cf := cf/v^d;
od;

[cf, terml];

end;
V1 :=
proc()
local sind, res, term;
sind :=
pet_varinto_cind(add(cat('B', q), q=1..6),
                 pet_cycleind_symm(10));

res := 0;

for term in expand(sind) do
    if nops(indets(term)) = 6 then
        res := res + term;
    fi;
od;


subs([seq(cat('B', q)=1, q=1..6)], res);

end;
W1 :=
proc()
local sind, res, term;
sind :=
pet_varinto_cind(add(cat('B', q), q=1..6),
                 pet_cycleind_cyclic(10));

res := 0;

for term in expand(sind) do
    if nops(indets(term)) = 6 then
        res := res + term;
    fi;
od;


subs([seq(cat('B', q)=1, q=1..6)], res);

end;
V2 :=
proc()
local ind, term, flat, res;
ind := pet_cycleind_symm(10);

res := 0;

for term in ind do
    flat := pet_flatten_term(term);

    res := res + flat[1]*
    6!*stirling2(nops(flat[2]), 6);
od;

res;

end;
W2 :=
proc()
local ind, term, flat, res;
ind := pet_cycleind_cyclic(10);

res := 0;

for term in ind do
    flat := pet_flatten_term(term);

    res := res + flat[1]*
    6!*stirling2(nops(flat[2]), 6);
od;

res;

end;
```

**Addendum 02 Jun 2016.** The case of the symmetric group has a simple closed form as seen at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808900/). In this particular instance we obtain

$$6! \times\frac{1}{10!} \sum_{q=1}^{10} \left[10\atop q\right] {q\brace 6} = 126.$$

Using the Stirling numbers of the first kind to count terms in the cycle index of the symmetric group that consist of $q$ cycles is of course much better than computing all terms of the cycle index.

The closed form for the cyclic group is
$$6! \times \frac{1}{10}\sum_{d|10} \varphi(d) {10/d\brace 6}
= 1643544.$$

The case of cyclic and dihedral symmetry including Maple code is documented at [OEIS A087854](https://oeis.org/draft/A087854) and [OEIS A273891](https://oeis.org/A273891).